# Java: List of names (String[]), how / can i display them using scrollbar?

Tags: java, string, jframe, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I have a String[] with 115 names. Now of course, i cannot fit all these names at once on a screen that i've set to be 1280 x 720.

I would like to display let's say 15-20 of these as buttons from the top of the screen until they hit the bottom, and the right side of the screen is an image, so we're lookin for a GridLayout(115, 1);

How would i go about to create this so that i can see a few names, and the rest of the are further down in the list and i access them with a scrollbar? My program extends JFrame and the item to the right is a 720 x 720 JLabel that is one big picture.

Did not add my code since there is no specific questions asked here, merely what classes i'd be using and how i would go about to proceed and use them. I've done some research on JScrollPane , JList and such.

Comment: Please do a little more research on say, scroll bars, before asking next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at

- [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Basically, a scroll pane controls a single component which acts as the view. The scroll pane acts like a window, allowing you to see a position of the view if it is larger then the scroll panes viewable size...

```
JList iist = new JList();
List.setModel(...);
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
// add sp to something ...
```

Comment: Sooo... add it to JFrame?

Comment: Add it to what ever you like, but, yes, it needs to be displayable on the screen at some stage –  MadProgrammer 12 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Using a [JScrollBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html), you can add a class with `myScrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(this)` so it will call your [AdjustmentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentListener.html)'s `adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)` method. In this method, use `e.getValue()` to get the value of the scroll bar. Interpret this value (with some good 'ol mathematics) to update the visibility/invisibility and x/y positions of your buttons!

For more, read up a [tutorial on JScrollBar's](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0820__JScrollBar.htm).

Don't forget to set the orientation, min and max values, etc.